# SQL Inline Function

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, user-defined-functions

I have a User Defined Function on database named `MyFunc`. It takes a string parameter and returns a scalar value.

And `MYTABLE` has two columns: `ID, NAME`

So Why is the following query error?

```
SELECT ID, MyFunc(NAME)
FROM MYTABLE
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Qualify it with schema

```
SELECT ID, dbo.MyFunc(NAME)
FROM MYTABLE
```

post the function if it doesn't work.